# ngRoute not loading one of my templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

ngRoute works for all my routes except for one(templates/:templateId). No error message in console when I click a button linking to that URL, just redirects me to the homepage as specified by the otherwise function.

Javascript:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/components/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/categories/:categoryId', {
        templateUrl: '/components/categories/categories.html',
        controller: 'CategoriesController'
    }).
    when('/templates', {
        templateUrl: '/components/templates/templates.html',
        controller: 'TemplatesController'
    }).
    when('templates/:templateId', {
        templateUrl: '/components/template/template.html',
        controller: 'TemplateController'
    }).
    when('/requests', {
        templateUrl: '/components/requests/requests.html',
    }).
    when('/requests/:requestId', {

    }).
    when('/modify', {

    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="template in templates">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">

        <a href="/templates/{{template.id}}">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        {{template.name}}
                    </h3>   
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{template.description}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I triple checked for spelling errors, but I'll check again, I'm not sure what is wrong, everything else works.

Comment: "... works for all my routes except for one" - which one?

Comment: `'/requests/:requestId'` has no template property, does that happen to be the one??

Comment: Ah... the `"templates"` one - you forgot a leading `/`: `when('/templates/:templateId', {..}`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it, it's templates/:templateId

Comment: @SpooXter, but should be `/templates/:templateId`

Comment: The leading dash... you kidding me! :D Thanks, I've been at it for soo long

Comment: @SpooXter, typo questions are typically best deleted since it doesn't provide much value to future visitors. In fact, I thought you did delete it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a slash ("/").
It should be `when('/templates/:templateId', {`

If this doesn't work, try the below one:
`when('/templates/:id', {`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Feel free to accept the solution as the answer if the solution is actually working for you and is useful to you. Thanks!!